# HackerRank - Virtual Function Practice

Tags: c++

This is just simple code to practice the use of [virtual functions](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/virtual-functions/problem) from a practice challenge in HackerRank. Could you give me some advice about the best practices and style?

This is just a simple exercise from HackerRank

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Person {
    protected:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    public:
    virtual void getdata() = 0;
    virtual void putdata() const = 0;
};
class Student final : public Person {  
    static inline int id_count = 0;
    std::array<int,6> marks;
    int cur_id;
    public:
    Student(){
        cur_id = ++Student::id_count;
    }
    void getdata() override {
        std::cin >> this->name;
        std::cin >> this->age;
        for (auto &mark : marks) {
            std::cin >> mark;
        }
    }
    void putdata() const override{
        std::cout << name << " " << age << " " << std::accumulate(marks.begin(), marks.end(), 0) << " " << cur_id << std::endl;
    }
};

class Professor final : public Person {
    static inline int id_count = 0;
    int publications;
    int cur_id;

    public:
    Professor(){
        cur_id = ++Professor::id_count;
    }
    void getdata() override {
        std::cin >> this->name;
        std::cin >> this->age;
        std::cin >> this->publications;
    }
    void putdata() const override {
        std::cout << name << " " << age << " " << publications << " " << cur_id << endl;
    }
};
```

Code provided by the question (cannot be edited):

> ```
>  int main(){
>     int n, val;
>     std::cin>>n; //The number of objects that is going to be created.
>     Person *per[n];
>
>     for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
>
>         std::cin>>val;
>         if(val == 1){
>             // If val is 1 current object is of type Professor
>             per[i] = new Professor;
>
>         }
>         else per[i] = new Student; // Else the current object is of type Student
>
>         per[i]->getdata(); // Get the data from the user.
>
>     }
>
>     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
>         per[i]->putdata(); // Print the required output for each object.
>
>     return 0;
>
> }
> ```

Comment: (Welcome to posting on CR!) To make contents not authored by you instantly identifiable, please make it a block quote: mark an use the "the `“”`/ *block quote* button" (or its keyboard short-cut) in the post editor or put `> ` before each line (works with nested contents like code-blocks, too).

Comment: Wow. That uneditable snippet of code is terrible. It lacks spaces between operators. Has bad names `n, val, per`. Leaks memory without even a comment about it. Bad naming of the virtual functions `getdata()` and `putdata()`. When we see `getfoo`, we expect that it is a getter function, and doesn't modify state, and `putfoo` is expected to be some kind of setter function (`setfoo` is a more common name), which does modify state; instead, they do the opposite.

Comment: @Justin hahaha that's good feedback, I also thought the same about the provided code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Be consistent.
  You use a blank line to separate classes `Student` and `Professor`: `Person` and `Student`deserve no less. (Same goes for *change in accessibility*; alternatives to a blank line include (less) indent.)
- Don't write, never present uncommented code.
  Use all machine/tool support you can get: have a look at [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).
- make classes (and functions) `final` when further derivation/overriding is bound to break something, only.
- Think of *derivation* as *extension* or *specialisation*.
  You declared common attributes for `Person`: try and do the same for behaviour, even if it is more cumbersome in C++ (& influenced languages) than in Simula: There, a `virtual` function gets to call `inner` - with common code before&after.
  In C++, I know no better than starting `Derived::f()` with `Base::f();`.
  In this example, `getdata()` & `putdata()` shouldn't be *pure* virtual:
  `Person::getdata()` should input name and age; `Person::putdata()` output them. We are stuck without a method to handle *specialised output is complete* imposing. One [*can*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27269423) define `void putdata() const { std::cout << toString() << std::endl; }` (with `toString()` facing the exact problem with `cur_id` "on the other side").
- Avoid overly long lines.

  ```
  name + " " + std::to_string(age)
       + " " + std::accumulate(marks.begin(), marks.end(), 0)
       + " " + std::to_string(cur_id)
  ```

  is easier to read and probably works just as well as a one-liner.

(While this review has been received exceedingly friendly,
the following code misses the mark *correct contemporary C++* by a mile.
(Hopefully closing in with revisions (incorporating advice from [Edward's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/183556/93149));
Having "fun" with IDEone - don't hold your breath.))

Shots from the hip:

```
/*! \brief Person sporting common attributes
 *         and get/putdata().
 *
 *  Attributes include name, age, and an in-subclass ID.
 *  getdata() reads from std::cin, starting with name&age;
 *  putdata() writes a line to std::cout.
 */
class Person {
 protected:
    //    const int cur_id;
    std::string name;
    int age;
    /*! terse human readable representation.
    */
    virtual std::string toString() const {
        return name + " " + std::to_string(age);
    }
    ~Person(){}
 public:
    /*! read name&age from std::cin.
     */
    virtual void getdata() {
        std::cin >> name >> age;
    }
    /*! putdata() writes a line to std::cout.
     */
    virtual void putdata(std::ostream &out = std::cout) const {
        out << toString() << std::endl;
    }
};

/*! Student adds marks for subjects to the common attributes.
 */
class Student : public Person {
    const int cur_id;
//    static std::atomic<int> id_count(0);
    std::array<int, 6> marks;
 protected:
    std::string toString() const override {
        return Person::toString()
        + " " + std::to_string(
            std::accumulate(marks.begin(), marks.end(), 0))
        + " " + std::to_string(cur_id);
    }
 public:
    static int id_count;// = 0;
    Student() : cur_id(++id_count) {}
    /*! read as Person from std::cin; add marks.
     */
    void getdata() override {
        Person::getdata();
        for (auto &mark : marks)
            std::cin >> mark;
    }
};

/*! Professor adds a publication count to the common attributes.
 */
class Professor final : public Person {
    const int cur_id;
//    static std::atomic<int> id_count(0);
    int publications;
 protected:
    std::string toString() const override {
        return Person::toString()
        + " " + std::to_string(publications)
        + " " + std::to_string(cur_id);
    }
 public:
    static int id_count;// = 0;
    Professor() : cur_id(++id_count) {}
    /*! read as Person from std::cin; add publications.
     */
    void getdata() override {
        Person::getdata();
        std::cin >> publications;
    }
};

int Student::id_count = 0;
int Professor::id_count = 0;
```

Comment: (Without a half-decent C++-environment in working condition, I have no idea whether, for example, `cur_id` works (please feel *invited* to edit): I want it unmodifiable after instantiation, I want *one* declaration for the entire hierarchy - I have a nagging feeling it not only doesn't work as presented: I must be missing a way not to repeat its initialisation.) (I keep forgetting about on-line environments - age showing:)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll work on the tips you have given me

Comment: (I never quite got `ostream` operator `<<` to be *the* method to *append human readable representation*.)

Answer (score 7):

It's unfortunate that we can't fix the provided code, as there is a lot more wrong with it than with your code, in my view.  Because this is a learning exercise and because it may benefit others who read this later, I'm going to review both pieces of code, starting with the code you actually wrote.

### Fix the bug

There is one instance in which `endl` is used without `std::` namespace.  It won't compile that way on my machine.  In any case, see the next suggestion.

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Understand `inline`

The `inline` specifier is new with C++17 and would allow one to, in this case, put the initialization of the member variable `id_count` within the header file, even if the header file is `#include`d in multiple other files (technically *translation units*).  In the context of the original code, there's not much real benefit to it, since there appears to be only one translation unit.  Using C++11 (or C++14) syntax, one could simply omit the `inline` keyword and then write

```
int Student::id_count{0};
```

outside the class definition.  Maybe you already knew all of that, but I think it's worthwhile clarifying what it means and how it works.

### Prefer modern initializers for constructors

The constructor could use the more modern initializer style rather than the old style you're currently using.  Instead of this:

```
Student(){
    cur_id = ++Student::id_count;
}
```

You could use this:

```
Student() :
    cur_id{++id_count}
{}
```

There is not a significant difference in this code, but it's a good habit to get into using.

### Avoid using explicit `this`

The current code includes this:

```
std::cin >> this->name;
std::cin >> this->age;
```

There's really no compelling reason to have `this->` here explicitly and no good reason not to chain the two extractions.  I'd write it like this:

```
std::cin >> name >> age;
```

### Think carefully about common code

Both the `Student` and `Professor` classes read in and write out the name and age first.  Since that's common to both, I'd be inclined to put that into the base `Person` class.  As an example, within the `Person` class:

```
virtual void getdata() {
    std::cin >> name >> age;
}
```

Then within the `Student` class:

```
void getdata() override {
    Person::getdata();           // call the base class
    for (auto &mark : marks) {   // do things unique to Student
        std::cin >> mark;
    }
}
```

This would also have the benefit that you could have `Person` member data `private` instead of `protected`.

### Consider explicitly defining all member data

What is the value of `name` just after a `Professor` object is created?  If you don't know, or if you know but think it ould be improved, I'd suggest explicitly defining all member data such that a constructed object has a known, rational state.

### Make your base class destructor virtual

By default, a compiler-generated destructor is concrete rather than virtual, but this leads to problems with collections of objects. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873515/why-should-the-destructor-of-base-classes-be-virtual) for more details on why.

### Consider the user

It would be convenient to be able to specify streams other than `std::cin` and `std::cout` for your classes.  One way to do that and still be able to use the given inteface code would be to have a default parameter like this:

```
void putdata(std::ostream &out = std::cout) const override;
```

That way, calling code that does not specify an argument will get `std::cout` but it's still possible to explicitly specify some other stream.

## Comments on given code harness

### Match `new` with `delete`

If you allocate memory using `new`, you should also free it using `delete` or your program will leak memory.  Since `main` uses `new` to create each `Person` object, it should also `delete` each such object.  Yes, the operating system will generally clean up such messes, but there's little advantage in creating them in the first place.

### Use more descriptive variable names

Single-letter variable names and extremely generic names like `val` make it harder to understand the program.  More meaningful variable names make the code easier to read and maintain.

### Check your `if` statements for proper braces

It's not helpful to use curly braces on the `if` clause and then omit them on the `else` clause.  Generally, I prefer to always have the braces.  It makes the intent clear and prevents bugs being introduced in maintenance.